# pgAdmin functions drop down not expanding

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4, postgresql-11

I am using PostgreSQL version 11.5 and pgAdmin4 Version 2.0

We migrated a database from Oracle to PostgreSQL 11.5 and it has around 30 user-defined functions in it.

In pgAdmin4 V2.0 I am unable to expand the `functions` drop-down on the left panel. The drop-down works just fine for other objects like Tables, Domains, Roles etc. I can find the functions from `pg_proc` table but do not know why am I unable to expand the drop-down, it just looks like its loading and it is as it is.

Comment: You should install the current pgAdmin4 version which is 4.23, 2.0 is extremely old and I doubt it is compatible with Postgres 11

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks. It is because Postgres introduced stored procedures from version 11. pgAdmin4 Version 2.0 was released when PostgreSQL version 11 was not released. The tool couldn't segregate functions and procedures which caused this issue.